# like within query

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

I am using **vs 2010** and want to perform a query on **sql server database**. But i have a problem i want to retrieves a row on the basis of name which i want to retrieves it using *second character of name* that is i don't know the first character that is **for example the name is nik as i enter i it will retrives a record which having nik as value of name column.**
Can any one guided me...I know following query what things i have to modified in it.

```
select * from table1 where name like '"&  n % &"'
```

Comment: holy cow, your question is quite confused. I think u use ms sql, so you are looking for `LIKE '_[letter searched]*'` _ acts as a wildcard for ONE sign, and * for 0..n

Comment: my question is that i want to search on the basis of second character that is i give second character and the result that match is retrieves.But the fact is i don't know the like query for this..

Comment: so @Najzero's comment should work for you then? e.g. If you want all names with second character `a` you would use `where name like '_a%'`

Comment: and how can i use textbox to take a character ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for example the name is nik as I enter i it will retrives a record which having nik as value of name column

try

```
select * from table1 where name like '_i%'
```

- [TSQL Like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

Comment: How can i used like with datagridview's default view to retrieves part of all rows ? can u have any idea .